# Elastic Search Unique Constraint

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am trying to make a function using elasticsearch v 1.4.4 in node.js to respond with an error

> ERROR :  duplicate _id

like in mongoDB when we try to insert a document in a index with the duplicate _Id.
Elastic search didn't provide such an error in spite of that it will **modify** the doc exist with that _id.

---

I have made a function which first make a query on elastic to find a record with that id throw an error.
But it doesn't work on real time.By real time i mean that if i try to insert docs with a new id then they will all insert and increases the version of doc.I have tried **_refresh** but doesn't work.

my function is something like..

```
function checkDuplicate(index,type,id,body){
    client.exists({index: index, type: type, id: id}, function (err, res) {
       if (res === false) {
            client.index({index: index, type: type,id:id, body: json}, function (err, response) {
                resp.send(JSON.stringify(response));
            })
        }
        else
            resp.send("Error : Duplicate index doc >>>>>>>>");
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `op_type` parameter (Operation Type) with the value `create` in your requests, this will return an error if you try create a document that already exists. From the [docs](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/docs-index_.html):

> The index operation also accepts an op_type that can be used to force a create operation, allowing for "put-if-absent" behavior. When create is used, the index operation will fail if a document by that id already exists in the index.

Comment: sir, i also want to apply this unique constraint on the fields. **example** let i have a field named e-mail and i don't want that two docs have the same e-mail id.